# Is the windows 8.1 tablet supports the Task Scheduler?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

The bellow c# code is to create a new task in windows task Sheduler, Is this supports in Windows Tablets?

```
ITaskService taskService = new TaskScheduler.TaskScheduler();
taskService.Connect();
ITaskDefinition taskDefinition = taskService.NewTask(0);
taskDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Testing Task 32";
taskDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Author = "XXX";
taskDefinition.Settings.Enabled = true;
taskDefinition.Settings.Hidden = false;
taskDefinition.Settings.Compatibility =   _TASK_COMPATIBILITY.TASK_COMPATIBILITY_V2_1;
```

Answer (score 0):

A windows store apps runs on a Windows tablet the same way it would on a Windows PC. If your task scheduler works after compiling the code with Visual Studio then it will work the same way on a tablet.

Answer (score 0):

The [Task Scheduler API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx) such as [ITaskService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381832(v=vs.85).aspx) are not supported in Windows Store apps. Windows Store apps are specifically blocked from making system-wide changes. You will need to create your task from a desktop app.

You can run desktop apps on Windows 8.1 tablets. Windows 8.1 tablets run the same versions of Windows 8.1 as desktop computers run.

Comment: Thanks for your Response. If there any other way to do this means please guide me.

Comment: If you want to schedule system tasks you must use a desktop app. If you want your Windows Store app to do something later there are several ways depending on what specifically you want to do. Check out background tasks, scheduled notifications, etc.